# Why didn’t EVE recognize the little cockroach as a living organism?

Tags: wall-e

Why didn’t EVE recognize the little cockroach as a living organism just like the plant? The cockroach possesses all characteristics sustainable in life as the plant with the exception of reproduction, although neither does the plant that has yet to show signs of reproduction.

Comment: I marvel how with almost no references, someone managed to answer this. =D ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - There's lots of reference; several junior novels, an art book, a script and dozens of DVD features that mention EVE

Comment: Plants represent the bottom rung of the ecosystem. If the planet supports plan life, then it can, in time, be inhabited by other forms of life. Strictly speaking, the cockroach should be dead by now, because what is there for it to eat?

Comment: @AJFaraday - Twinkies

Comment: @Valorum There's a lot of cockroaches in the world, and a limited supply of packaged food. 'nuff said.

Comment: @AJFaraday - I don't see evidence of *lots* of cockroaches, I only see evidence of three

Comment: @Valorum EVE is not Eve... I think Eve is a pretty common name in fiction.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. - In the novelisations, Her (its?) name is consistently spelled EVE, not Eve.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not a sci-fi buff... and that's why if we read the question we see it was written with Eve. That's why I was surprised people immediately understood who the OP was refering to. =D

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea - I was merely being accurate

Comment: @AJFaraday Cockroaches are extremely omnivorous, some species also cannibalistic. With the amount of waste left behind on the planet, there may have been enough to sustain an ever-dwindling population of cockroaches. A more serious objection, I would think, would be that with no plant life at all on the planet for 800 years, some kind of runaway greenhouse effect would likely have started, making the planet completely uninhabitable and unable to sustain new plant life.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - If no plant life can arise if there's no plant life, then how did plant life arise in the first place?

Comment: I thought my answer to this was nicely comprehensive, drawing from three different sources (other than the film). Is there anything else you think I should address before you consider an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum Over a much longer period than just 800 years. And also on a very different planet to what Earth is now, during a time when there was little to no risk of runaway greenhouse effects.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I suspect that the potential impact of a dieback of surface plant life is actually pretty small over a period as short as a thousand years. I saw an article in New Scientist that talked about the atmosphere becoming unbreathable for humans (in the event that all plant life on the planet died suddenly) in something like *52,000* years.

Comment: @Valurm not that we would last more than a few months (or whatever current food stores would last) without plant life, so we wouldn't find out whether it's 52,000 years or 10 ;) And that's assuming whatever made plant life impossible didn't kill us just as fast!

Answer (score 146):

As you can see from [this DVD insert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVIk9AvVXJw) (describing the various robots and their primary focus) EVE is an Extraterrestrial ***Vegetation*** Evaluator. Her main focus is to review organic, read *plant organic*, life on the planets that she surveys.

[image]

As such, a life-form *other than a plant* wouldn't register on her scanners.

> WALL-E’s visitor is a probe-bot who has been **sent to Earth to check
> for signs of plant life.** The Extra-terrestrial Vegetation Evaluator,
> otherwise known as EVE, takes her mission very seriously.
>
> <sub><sup>[WALL-E: The Intergalactic Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3685236-wall-e)</sup></sub>

---

You might want to note that on a purely personal level she absolutely does recognise the roach as a living being.

> Eve finds the insect intriguing. Lowers her arm. The end separates into individual hovering sections...
>
> <sub><sup>[Wall-E Script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html)</sup></sub>

But when she scans Wall•E *and* the cockroach together, she finds that they're simply *"not what she was looking for"* (e.g. plant life).

> She let the roach get closer. The little bug intrigued her, and she let him crawl up her arm. WALL · E heard her emit a series of electronic beeps. She was giggling! The roach must have tickled her.
>
> ...
>
> She slowly approached the shivering box. The cockroach ran down EVE’s
> blaster arm and hopped onto his master. EVE’s blue light scanned WALL·E. NEGATIVE. **He was not what she was looking for.** She retracted her
> blaster arm and glided away.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wall•E - Official Junior novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3359002-wall-e-disney-pixar-wall-e)</sup></sub>

Comment: Given that she was scanning for vegetation _on Earth_, she should technically be a _Terrestrial_ Vegetation Evaluator.

Comment: I don't totally agree with Sean. EVE's function, by design, could be Extraterrestrial, however after the events on Earth transpired, is being used Terrestrially. Using a robot in an unforeseen way would not change it's acronym.

Comment: @Sean She was **on** Earth, but **from** Space - beyond (*extra*) Earth (*terrestrial*).  An "Extraterrestrial Vegetation-Evaluator", not an "Extraterrestrial-Vegetation Evaluator"

Comment: @Chronocidal - I read it differently. In my head, her typical role is to evaluate life on the various planets that BNL can get to in their exploration ships. Once Operation Recolonise was implemented, her role changed to periodically evaluating life on Earth. So she's a *restasked* EVE probe.

Answer (score 68):

Unlike a plant, a cockroach does not show that the planet has started to recover, just that it has not yet run out of food waste yet.

More importantly:  "EVE" stands for "Extraterrestrial *Vegetation* Evaluator" - as the name suggests, she is **specifically** designed to search for Flora, not Fauna, (i.e. to search for Plant Life, not Animal Life).

Comment: This is important! Roaches are great at scavenging. Even in the current time, it is predicted that roaches can easily survive a nuclear holocaust.

Answer (score 12):

It is commonly thought that cockroaches are uniquely capable of surviving even in a highly radioactive environment.

Therefore the presence of a cockroach is not an indicator of an envoriment being inhabitable, or even safe to be in.

Comment: To clarify are you saying that Eve _did_ recognise the cockroach as a living organism but discounted it because of the nature of a cockroach?

Comment: For the record, cockroaches are *particularly* susceptible to radiation poisoning and would likely be among the first class of creatures to die in a nuclear holocaust

Comment: @Valorum: Compared to (say) fruit flies, yes. Compared to (say) humans, it's precisely the opposite.

Comment: I feel this answer should get more upvotes. The scene was clearly a nod to the fabled hardiness of cockroaches, and their alleged ability to survive natural disasters.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Precisely. Note that it scans the cockroach more thoroughly than any of the inanimate matter around.

Comment: @Valorum Well, not exactly. They used the cockroach in the movie because it is a widespread belief that they are all that will be left after the nuclear holocaust (may it never come to be). Invertebraes in general have much bigger chances of surviving, so cockroach is not more susceptible than a human let's say. Note also that there are around 5000 species of cockroaches - so perhaps some of them have a particular resistance.