Is Wall-E's best friend on Earth, the cockroach, a real cockroach or a robot?
Wall-E had a cockroach friend while on Earth. I am wondering, was it a real cockroach, or a robot cockroach?
If it was a real cockroach, what did it eat, considering there had been no plants on Earth for centuries?
If it was a robot cockroach, where did it get its electricity from?

Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207449/why-didn-t-eve-recognize-the-little-cockroach-as-a-living-organism

There is a fresh Twinkie-like product* for Hal the roach to sleep in.  Since Twinkies (not really, but according to folklore) never go bad,** there ought to be millions of them out there for him to collect and devour.

*Apparently, it is officially a "Kremie."
**Also, there is a lot of folklore about cockroaches surviving and even thriving after all (or almost all) other multicellular life on Earth has been catastrophically wiped out.

"Cockroaches can survive anything." - Dr. Henry Pym

I wonder if Dr. Pym ever heard about water bears though.

Water bears, unlike polar bears, are pretty tiny in an eye wise sense.

Also, cockroaches survive today because we kindly provide them the food and the heating that they need to survive in most climates. Take us out, and the cockroaches would only survive in warmer regions.

@SJuan76 Something something global warming something.

The other answer notes what the cockroach eats, so I'll focus on whether it's a real cockroach or a robot.
The script calls it an "insect" and a "cockroach" multiple times, and never a robot, so it's an actual cockroach.
Examples:

Wall-E attaches a lunch cooler to his back.
Whistles for his pet COCKROACH.
The insect hops on his shoulder.


The insect mopes.
Droops its little antennae.

